# digest('hex') function not found using CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, salt, cryptojs

I am using crypto-js.js and creating a `sha512` function there for creating a variable `hash1`. we are successfully creating the hash and then updating hash with password but after that not able to use digest function.

```
var sha512 = function (password, salt) {

    var hash1 = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA512, salt); /** Hashing algorithm sha512 */

    hash1.update(password);

    var value = hash1.digest('hex');
    return {
        salt: salt,
        passwordHash: value
    };
};
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: mine gives an error (hash1.update is not a function) in the "hash1.update(password);" line. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`digest` is an HMAC method in the Node.js **crypto** module.  The equivalent method in CryptoJS is `finalize`.  The result of `finalize` is a CryptoJS `WordArray` object.  To get a hex string, use the `WordArray` in a context where it will be treated as a string.  Specifically, replace your:

```
    var value = hash1.digest('hex');
```

with:

```
    var value = '' + hash1.finalize();
```